# Displaying Snackbar inside a SearchDelegate

Tags: flutter

I am using a SearchDelegate and want to display a Snackbar when the user tries to perform a search with an empty query. I've tried returning Scaffold widgets from both the `buildSuggestions` and `buildResults` methods and then using a Builder / GlobalKey inside the `buildResults` method to display a message to the user if the search query has a length of zero. However this leads to the Scaffold's state being updated during the render method which throws an exception. Has anyone dealt with a similar challenge? Seems like a common use case that you would want to display a Snackbar inside your search delegate, yet I can't seem to fathom an easy way to do it.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  List<Drug> drugList = new List<Drug>();
  DataSearch(Future<List<Drug>> listDrugName) {
    this.drugListFuture = listDrugName;
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    // actions for app bar
    return [
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () {
            query = "";
          })
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    // leading icon on the left of app bar
    return IconButton(
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
            icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow, progress: transitionAnimation),
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // show result from selection
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder(
        future: db.getDrugEntries(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.length < 1) {
            return new Center(
                child: new LoadingIndicator(Constants.msgLoading));
          } else {
            drugList = snapshot.data;
            // show when user searches for something
            final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
                ? drugList
                : drugList
                    .where((r) =>
                        (r.drugId.toLowerCase())
                            .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                        (r.fullDrugName.toLowerCase())
                            .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                        (r.otherName.toLowerCase())
                            .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                        (r.tradeName.toLowerCase())
                            .contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                    .toList();
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                String drugName = suggestionList[index].genericName;
                String drugId = suggestionList[index].drugId;
                int queryIndex = drugName.indexOf(query);
                if (queryIndex == -1) {
                  queryIndex = 0;
                }
                int queryIndexEnd = queryIndex + query.length;


                return Container(button//...onTap:_launchExtraContent(context,drugId);
              },
              itemCount: suggestionList.length,
            );
          }
        });
  }



  _

  _launchExtraContent(BuildContext context, StringtheFileName) async {
    try {
      //......
    } catch (e) {
      _showSnackBar(context,'ERROR: Unable to retrieve file please submit a bug report');
    }
  }

  void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
      content: new Text(
        text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's been a while, but I believe this approach did not work for me inside the SearchDelegate (because there was no Scaffold preceding the SearchDelegate in the widget tree). Can you share more code, so I can get a bit more context on where this is called, please?

Comment: updated answer, basically in my listview I return a list of items that have buttons which upon tap will open a document that the app should have downloaded from a server `_launchExtraContent`. However if the app is unable to download the file then when an exception is thrown it is caught and a snackbar displays the error message.